# iTextSharp + CKEditor html to pdf, POL character

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, ckeditor, itext

I am stuck at fails to implement polish characters to my generator. I have tried many of methods suggested by stackoverflow, private forums and etc but without result. This is code I use:

```
Document document = new Document();
try
{
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/" + currentNumberOfElement + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
    currentNumberOfElement++;
    document.Open();
    List<IElement> list = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(tmpResult), null);
    for (int k = 0; k < list.Count; k++)
    {
        document.Add((IElement)list[k]);
    }
    document.Close();
}
catch (Exception exx)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine(exx.StackTrace);
    Console.Error.WriteLine(exx.Message);
}
```

As `tmpResult` I have placed string from CKEditor which contains polish characters. Worth noticing if fact that `&oacute;` is contained in, works good and gives "ó" but when I tried to change all special chars with:

```
public string HTMLEncodeSpecialChars(string text)
{
  System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
  foreach (char c in text){
    if(c>127) // special chars
      sb.Append(String.Format("&#{0};",(int)c));
    else
      sb.Append(c);
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

It doesn't work as I thought it would be and now I am stuck after a day of work. Anyone have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: It might help to mention how it doesn't work - when you say "as I thought it would", that doesn't really describe what you expected to get and what you got. How about using UTF-8 everywhere and just not using encoded characters `&#128;` at all? I don't know if iTextSharp supports it but I would be surprised if it didn't.

Comment: @Nenotlep By this I mean that this method should work also for other encoded special characters. I expected to get fully encoded PDF and got still only "ó" right where all other special chars as "ń","ż" (...) didn't work even though they were encoded the same way as "ó". All the text is (or should be) encoded in UTF-8 by default and I don't have big knowledge about iTextSharp too but as far as I seen there are many ways to deal with such issue and none of them worked (I have typed iTextSharp polish characters on google and ran through pages for day and tried all I found and got nothing)